# RESTAssured - response.getBody().getList(<ListName>) is returning me a null collection

Tags: java, rest, automated-tests, web-api-testing, testautomationfx

Sorry about the long post in advance.Peculiar problem and I guess it knowing the answers to such ones that separate the men from the boys.

Here goes:
I built an API Testing framework over RESTassured that allows setup through an excel sheet. One of it's steps is to take the snippets of the path, put it together and extract the value at the path from the JSON Response.

In this case I have the following code (the trims are out of frustration :P)

A snippet of the code is

```
String listKey = requestItem.getRequestItem().get("ENTITY_TYPE").trim();
String listName = assertionItem.get("LIST_NAME").trim();
String innerObjectListParamPath = listKey+"."+listName;
String listPrimaryKeyName = assertionItem.get("LIST_KEY_NAME").trim();
String expectedListPrimaryKeyValue = assertionItem.get("LIST_ROW_ID").trim();
String resParamKey = assertionItem.get("RES_PARAM_KEY").trim();
List<Object> innerObjectList = response.getBody().jsonPath().getList(innerObjectListParamPath.trim());
```

This resides in a loop that iterates over a list of HashMaps that is constructed from an excel data sheet partially using fillo and partially using Apache POI.

Now here's my problem:

`innerObjectList` **always** returns null.

Thexpath is correct, I ran the code for another api with the same feature and it works fine. In fact the 
value for `"innerObjectListParamPath"`the value evaluates to `"interestType.interestTypeCriteria"`

when I > `logger.info( response.getBody().jsonPath().getList(interestType.interestTypeCriteria"))`, aka, hardcode the path, it works like a charm.

I upgraded my POM to the latest versions of rest assured as follows:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>4.1.2</version> -->
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Also I'm using fillo and apache poi to read the excel data.

Any help with regards to what I could tweak would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Dan - have you fixed it?

Comment: @UIResponder. I believe I have because the framework has been running correctly with it's enhancements.

Comment: Unsure what I fixed to make it though. It was more than 9 months back. Unsure if i fixed the response handling or the way I parsed a generic response

Comment: alright, yo! ....